# TinyMCEv4 editor content wrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, tinymce

I am having some difficulties with setting up WYSIWYG TinyMCE (I'm using v.4.3.3).

I would like editor content to be rendered with my site's CSS. I have already setted up `content_css` variable to my css file(s), but it is not sufficient. Text that is written in editor is going to be new post body. Beacause of that it is going to be wrapped in few containers (something like `<div id="some_ID"><div id="another_ID"><article><section>(WYSIWYG TEXT)</section></article></div></div>`), and since in WYSIWYG preview there are no wrappers, it is not rendered properly.

Is there some (simple) way to wrap editor content with suitable wrappers, or would you rather suggest to somehow edit CSS file, so it will render content correctly without wrappers (I don't realy like this idea, but if it will be the only way to do that, I would have to go with that).

EDIT: To be clear, I don't want to submit those added wrappers, I just want them to change the way editor content is being rendered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to use

```
forced_root_block:''
```

in editing mode, and only in preview add the needed wrappers by using jQuery's append() and prepend()

Comment: that's one way to do it, but this way the content is going to be rendered properly only in preview mode, which kinda makes it not-WYSIWYG...

Comment: So 1) add proper wrapper with class/es which will cover all styles what you need for proper display and remove useless in preview using jQuery 2) Create tinyMce template which will cover all needed styles, it will also work in preview

Comment: 1) as I replied - it will just make preview look good, and is not what I want to achieve...
2) template might be a solution, but I need complex structure (see my question for example) and template just stops on first `div` it finds...

Comment: in forced_root_block add wrapper with class which you need to display it properly in EDIT MODE

Comment: OK, sorry, took me a while to understand what do you mean :) right now it more or less works (I add needed wrappers with jQuery when TinyMCE starts), there is only one issue - since wrappers are added inside editor they become part of text input. They are submitted with form (that's not a big issue, I can strip them off before saving the data), but they also can be deleted accidently by user if (s)he wants to clear text field. Any idea about that?